# Not able to run web api files in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, android-studio, http, dart

I am trying to build a login page using flutter and MySQL .I have connected to the dataBase but when  i try running the login.php file I am getting the error "**XMLHttpRequest error**".I tried downgrading the http to 0.13.2 version but it does not  work .
Here is the error :-

```
Running with sound null safety 
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59586/vPwdx1ozx5U=/ws
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 908:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22                                                                                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1687:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 160:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 593:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1232:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37332:58                              <fn>


    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:59514/dart_sdk.js:5074:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:59514/dart_sdk.js:38925:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:59514/dart_sdk.js:38921:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:59514/dart_sdk.js:38778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:59514/dart_sdk.js:38784:13)
    at http://localhost:59514/dart_sdk.js:34519:9
```

Here is my Code for the login page:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'mainpg.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
class login1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const login1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _login1State createState() => _login1State();
}

class _login1State extends State<login1> {
  TextEditingController username = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  Future  login() async{

    if(username.text == ""||password.text == "")
      {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Both fields cant be blank!",
            toastLength:Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            fontSize: 16.0,
        );
      }
    else{
        var url =Uri.parse('http://localhost/localconnect/login.php');
        var response = await http.post(url,headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
            body:jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "username":username.text,
        "password":password.text,
        }),);
        var data = json.decode(response.body);
        if(data == "success"){
        Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context){
        return const mainpage();
        }));
        }
        else{
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "The user and Password combination does not exist!",
        toastLength:Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
        fontSize: 16.0,
        );
        }
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body:SafeArea(
        child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children:[
              Expanded(
                flex:2,
                child: Container(
                    width:1,
                    color:Colors.white,
                    child:Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children:   [
                        const Image(
                          image: AssetImage('image/foodexpress2.jpg'),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height:5),
                        const Text(
                            'Food Express',
                            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                            style:TextStyle(
                              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                              fontSize:40,
                              color:Colors.red,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              fontWeight:FontWeight.w700,
                            )
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height:30),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            color:Colors.grey[200],
                            child: Column(
                              children:  [
                                const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                      'Login',
                                      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                      style:TextStyle(
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                        fontSize:25,
                                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                        color:Colors.redAccent,
                                        fontWeight:FontWeight.w700,
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
                                 Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:25.0,right:25.0),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: username,
                                    autofocus: true,
                                  //  onChanged:(value){
                                      //Username= value;
                                    //  print(Username);
                                  //  },
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    cursorColor: Color(0xFFC41A38),
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      hintText:'Enter username',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontStyle:FontStyle.italic,
                                        color:Color(0xFF1B1F32),
                                      ),
                                      contentPadding:
                                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                                      ),
                                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 1.0),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                                      ),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 2.0),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height:20),
                                  Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:25.0,right:25.0),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller:password,
                                    //onChanged:(value){
                                     // Password = value;
                                    //  print(Password);
                                  //  },
                                    autofocus:true,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    obscureText: true,
                                    cursorColor: const Color(0xFFC41A38),
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(

                                      hintText:'Enter Password',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontStyle:FontStyle.italic,
                                        color:Color(0xFF1B1F32),
                                      ),
                                      contentPadding:
                                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                                      ),
                                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 1.0),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                                      ),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 2.0),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height:20),
                                Material(
                                    elevation:5.0,
                                    color:Colors.blueAccent,
                                    borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                    child:MaterialButton(
                                        onPressed:(){
                                          setState((){
                                            login();
                                          });
                                        },
                                        minWidth:620,
                                        height:60.0,
                                        child:const Text(
                                          'Log In',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex:2,
                child: Container(
                  width: 1,
                  decoration:  const BoxDecoration(
                      image:  DecorationImage(
                        image:  AssetImage('image/food1.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      )
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As more as I know, it all related to ur base URL nothing with the dependencies or dart APIs all you have to do is to get ip address and access ur local server by IP address from android or ios devices/emulator

so try to avoid localhost in baseurl
and then test it and report back :)

Comment: I get the same error .

Comment: kindly replace the local host with ip address or deploy your db to server and then try it and report back

Comment: I tried putting this "http:// 192.168.0.113/localconnect/login.php" dosent work bro:(

Comment: It showing an invalid url if i put my Ip address for localhost